# Html emails <hr> styling issue on Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have used the `<hr>` tag to separate the rows, which is showing double lines in outlook emails.
But I want just a single line to be displayed. How can I rectify this?

[image]

I have used the following code

```
<hr style="border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #0a0a0a;box-shadow:none;margin-bottom:0;">
```

All answers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `outline:none;` might remove the double line issue in outlook emails.

```html
<hr style="border:none;outline:none;border-bottom:1px solid #0a0a0a;box-shadow:none;margin-bottom:0;"/>
```

Or, you can remove outlines, borders and give a height and background color as:

```html
<hr style="border:none;outline:none;height:1px;background:#0a0a0a;box-shadow:none;margin-bottom:0;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different way.

```html
<div style="border-top: 1px dotted #999999;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For best cross-email compatibility, I use border. You can do that on the `<td>`, or other block level element like `<p>`.

Here, I'd use a paragraph like so:

```
`<p style="border-top:1px solid #0a0a0a;line-height: 0;font-size:0;margin:10px 0;">&nbsp;</p>`
```

Adjust the margin to what you need. The line-height and font-size are needed so that there is not an additional space caused by the "text" (non-breaking space).